# How to unmask a SystemD service unit on a remote machine?

Tags: services, remote, systemd

I have a huuuge problem and need help. While trying to speed up the boot process on my LMDE4 machine by disabling/masking "unnecessary" services, I masked `systemd-logind.service` and can no longer boot. I've already tried booting into the console by editing the grub2 configuration, but the boot process interrupts with an error:

```
Cannot open access to console, the root account is locked.
See sulogin(8) man page for more details.

Press Enter to continue.
```

So I prepared a live LMDE4 USB stick, booted into the recovery system, unlocked and mounted the LUKS encrypted LVM host volume (the one I've locked myself out of), and now at least I have access to the file system.

How can I proceed from here to unmask the service unit on that volume?

The problem is that doing `sudo systemctl unmask systemd-logind.service` will unmask the service unit of the running USB recovery system and not the one on the host system. How does systemd recognize a service unit as masked? Is it something within the service file, i.e. can I just modify its content in order to unmask the service, or is it more involved?

I already checked `file /lib/systemd/system/systemd-logind.service` and it says

```
./systemd-logind.service: ASCII text
```

so it does not seem to be pointing to `/dev/null` (as usually happens when a service unit is masked by `systemctl mask name.service`).

Answer (score 0):

Try to chroot into the System.

To do this open a terminal and run the following command

```
chroot YOURDRIVEMOUNTHERE
```

Replace YOURDRIVEMOUNTHERE with the Mount point where the broken System's Drive is Mounted.

Then check if `/etc/systemd/system/systemd-logind.service` is a symboilc link to /dev/null By running this command.

```
file /etc/systemd/system/systemd-logind.service
```

If it is run the following commands in the chroot bash shell.

```
rm  /etc/systemd/system/systemd-logind.service
ln -s /lib/systemd/system/systemd-logind.service /etc/systemd/system/systemd-logind.service
```

And try to boot Linux.

If it fails go back into the chroot bash shell and run

```
passwd root
```

And Set A Password.
Boot into linux console and enter the password and run the following Command.

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable systemd-logind.service
```

And Reboot

Afterwards you can disable access to the root account and only allow sudo root access if you want to by running

```
sudo passwd -l root
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122660/discussion-on-answer-by-annpocoyo-how-to-unmask-a-systemd-service-unit-on-a-remo).